# R haven::write_dta() error

Tags: r, export, stata

I am using the package rio to export a R file to Stata and I get an error

```
data(cars)
library(rio)
export(cars, "cars.dta")

Error in write_dta_(data, normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE), version = stata_file_format(version)) : Writing failure: Unable to write data.
```

I know package Rio is using haven::write_dta() function and I have try each parameters without sucessfull

Comment: This might be an error with `rio`, not `haven`. Does `write_dta(cars, "cars.dta")` work?

Comment: An alternative would be ```write.dta``` from the ```foreign``` package

Comment: This works on my end. Either it has been fixed or the error was not code-related.